# Capture UIScrollView to an image with the right zoomScale

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I'm using this code to take a Snapshot of the `UIScrollView` . My problem is that the snap shot will always take the 1.0f zoomscale of the `UIScrollView` While I want to snapshot the all content in the `UIScrollView`. How can I accomplish this?

```
CGRect rect = [viewToCapture bounds];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size,YES,0.0f);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[viewToCapture.layer renderInContext:context];
UIImage *capturedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return capturedImage;
```

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611350/capturing-uiscrollview-off-screen-content?rq=1

Comment: I didn't understand from the answer how saving the frame size helps me.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this below url :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15804107/1443976

Comment: You could have given the link to here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799805/how-do-i-capture-a-zoomed-uiimageview-inside-of-a-scrollview-to-crop and that doesn't solve my problem

Comment: No. That's a different problem that the one i'm having

Comment: now what's the issue then ?? means how much is the zoomscale you want the complete content of the scrollview ?? am i right or wrong ?